# Storing and retrieving enums in SQLite with Java

Tags: java, enums

I am in the need of being able to store and retrieve enums from a SQLite database, which I have solved with combined use of a wrapper class and enums, but I feel it's very poorly designed.

Every time I want to add a new item to the list of enums, I have to add it in three different places.

The enum must contain:

- an int (or string) to represent it
- a text string giving further text about the enum itself
- a method to somehow restore its state from the database

Currently it is implemented like this:

```
public class items
{
    public enum types {
        FOO(0),
        BAR(1), 
        BAZ(2);

        private final int _value;
        types(int value){_value = value;}
        public int value(){return _value;}
    }

    public static types Get(int i)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                return types.FOO;
            case 1:
                return types.BAR;
            case 2:
                return types.BAZ;   
            default: 
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static String Get(Typer type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case FOO:
                return "This is foo!";
            case BAR:
                return "This is bar!";
            case BAZ:
                return "This is baz!";
            default:
                return "No good!";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An enum value has `FOO.ordinal()` function is a numeric representation of a value. The function returns its number between zero and `n-1` where `n` - how much enum values do you have. Then you could use `types.values()[i]` to retrieve back a value by the number. But you should keep in mind that it's not allowed to reorder or add new enum in the middle, because the numbers will be changed.

Also, you could use `types.valueOf("FOO")` and `FOO.name()` for a string representation of the enum value. It's safer to use, because it doesn't depend on the declaration order.

Comment: but if you are going to store the enum into string, you must not never change the name of the enum value .. each one has its advantage and disadvantage

Comment: I guess using ordinal is more risky as one can easily add a new enum type in between. But changing name has a little less probability. Well thats what I feel, I might be wrong

Comment: @RahulVerma Just cover with tests if important - and no risk. But storing single `int` value is usually much more efficient than a string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the enum name for storing and retrieving.

`types.valueOf("FOO")` should deliver `types.FOO` and `types.FOO.name()` gives you the name of the enum.

If you want to retrieve it by a member variable, you can do something like this:

```
public static Types byValue(final int value) {
    Types returnvalue = FOO; // default returnvalue
    for (final Types type : Types.values()) {
        if (type.value == value) {
            returnvalue = type;
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnvalue;
}
```

If it is performance critical, you can put all the types into a static map with the 'value' as the key. Then you don't need the loop and say only `valueMap.get(value)`. The map should be initialized in a static block in the enum.

For the extra text value you can give the enum a second member variable of type String with a getter. So the associated int and String values are only in the initialization.

For example,

```
FOO(0,"Hello I'm Foo"),
BAA(1,"Hello I'm Baa"),
...
```